Fetch and set up remote tracking with a branch not listed in the git fetch config
I work in a very large monorepo, so by default the fetch configuration is constrained to avoid pulling down thousands of branches and slowing down git (i.e. fetch = +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master)
If I want to pull down someone else's branch, I can still easily do that by calling
git fetch origin <branch-name>:<branch-name>

which creates a remote branch and a local branch at the current state. However, it does not set up remote tracking between the two, so I cannot pull changes to the local branch.
I tried setting up remote tracking manually with git branch -u origin/<branch-name>, but I get the following error:
fatal: cannot set up tracking information; starting point 'origin/<branch-name>' is not a branch

I see origin/<branch-name> when I call git branch -r --list and git show works on it, so I'm perplexed by this error. Is there another way I can go about this without having to change the fetch config for that one branch?
Apologies if this is a duplicate question, I searched and could not find a definitive answer. Most don't address the fetch config not including the desired branch. I tried the methods listed here. But I still get that same error.

Maybe you could set up a minimal reproducible example, using an actual public repo from GitHub and an actual sequence of terminal commands to run?

@Quuxplusone good call. I'll see if I can set that up this week.

@Quuxplusone added some STRs in an answer (didn't fit in a comment). I did find something that works, but it would be nice to be able to do it without pushing the branch.

Here's a rundown what I was trying to do, which you can reproduce using webpack:
git clone https://github.com/webpack/webpack.git --single-branch

git config --list # should show “remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/main:refs/remotes/origin/main”

git fetch --refmap="+refs/heads/<some-other-branch>:refs/remotes/origin/<some-other-branch>" origin <some-other-branch>

git branch -r # should show new remote branch

git checkout -b <some-other-branch> origin/<some-other-branch> # Checks out new branch at same commit, but not tracking

git branch -u origin/<some-other-branch> # get error “fatal: cannot set up tracking information; starting point 'origin/<some-other-branch>' is not a branch”


But I did find that the following will get me what I need. Calling push on someone else's branch made me nervous, but if I'm not forcing then it should be fine.
git fetch origin <branch-name>:<branch-name>
git push -u origin <branch-name>

